# Logging all unhandled exception under hosted environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-logging, unhandled-exception

I knew that I am re-inventing the wheel. But still, I have to do it as I am instructed to do so :D. 
I have to log all unhandled exception of my asp.net website. I am able to dynamically catch all exceptions but I am not able to retrieve the actual class and method name. 
Everytime I got Global_asax as class name and Application_Error as the method name. Below is my code.

```
/// <summary>
/// Determines the log type and saves log to database. Use logtype 1 for exception logging 
/// and 2 for normal audit trail.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="obj">Type of object. Accepts exception or audit log string.</param>
/// <param name="logType">Type of logging. Use LogTypes.Exception for Exception  and LogTypes.Audit for Normal Logging</param>
/// <param name="fileName"></param>
/// <param name="userId">optional parameter. Accepts userid as integer</param>
/// <param name="userName">optional parameter. Accepts username as string</param>
/// <param name="memberName"></param>
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
private void Log( LogTypes logType, object obj, string memberName,string fileName, int userId = 0, string userName = "")
{
    var appLog = new ApplicationLog();
    var stackFrame = new StackFrame(2,true);
    try
    {
        var isHosted = HostingEnvironment.IsHosted;
        appLog.UserId = userId;
        appLog.UserName = userName;
        appLog.InstanceName = ConfigurationSettingsHelper.InstanceName;
        appLog.LoggedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;

        if (isHosted)
        {
            appLog.ProjectName = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName();
            appLog.FilePath = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
        }
        else
        {
            appLog.ProjectName= Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name;
            appLog.FilePath = fileName;
        }

        if (logType == LogTypes.Exception)
        {
            appLog.LogType = 1;
            if (obj is Exception  ex)
            {
                var declaringType = ex.TargetSite.DeclaringType;
                if (declaringType != null)
                {
                    appLog.ClassName = declaringType.FullName;
                    appLog.MethodName = ex.TargetSite.Name;
                }
                appLog.LogDetails = ex.ToString();
                appLog.Message = ex.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                appLog.ClassName = stackFrame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
                appLog.MethodName = memberName;
                appLog.LogDetails = obj.ToString();
                appLog.Message = "User defined custom exception";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            appLog.LogType = 2;
            appLog.ClassName = stackFrame.GetMethod().DeclaringType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
            appLog.MethodName = memberName;
            appLog.LogDetails = obj.ToString();
            appLog.Message = "User defined custom exception";
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //In case of unhandled exceptions.Try logging internal exception once.
        //If failed, pass by silently.
        try
        {
            appLog = new ApplicationLog
            {
                UserId = userId,
                UserName = userName,
                FilePath = new StackFrame(1).GetFileName(),
                Message = ex.Message,
                InstanceName = ConfigurationSettingsHelper.InstanceName,
                ProjectName = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().GetName().Name,
                LoggedOn = DateTime.UtcNow,
                LogType = 1,
                LogDetails = ex.ToString()
            };
            if (ex.TargetSite.DeclaringType != null)
                appLog.ClassName = ex.TargetSite.DeclaringType.FullName;
            appLog.MethodName = ex.TargetSite.Name;
        }
        finally
        {
            HttpWebMethods.PostAsync(ConfigurationSettingsHelper.LoggerApiBaseAddress,
                ConfigurationSettingsHelper.SaveLogEndpoint, appLog);
        } // intentionally eating exception}
    }
    finally
    {
        HttpWebMethods.PostAsync(ConfigurationSettingsHelper.LoggerApiBaseAddress,
            ConfigurationSettingsHelper.SaveLogEndpoint, appLog);
    }
}
```

It's logging all good at all places. But for the case of any unhandled exceptions, I need to capture the class name and method name. But instead, its giving me the global.asax details.

Its a class library and i want it work as same as Global.asax works. Automatically recognizes all errors.

Please help.

Comment: Why don’t you just look at the stack trace? Why do you need to isolate method name and class name?

Comment: Actually we are logging all exceptions in sql database for our developers to analyze. And we have a UI where my supervisor wants to search on class and method names. As searching in stacktrace will be little lazy.

Comment: Your supervisor sounds like he doesn’t know what he’s doing. Install Serilog, SEQ, and add a couple lines of code and you’ll have a far better system than this cobbled together hodgepodge.

Comment: I knew :D. After all BOSS is always right.

Comment: Logging the class name and method name is silly. What class? What method? Is it the class that throws the original exception? The first level of your applications code? Th last level of your application code? What if there’s inner exceptions or aggregate exceptions? You see how pointless it is to examine the method and class name? It could be any of several, and you’d need to examine the stack trace, not a random class and method name.